# Where is street level data stored in mbtiles files?

Tags: mbtiles

I have a .mbtiles file loaded into an SQLite browser, trying to find street level data (road names, A/M roads etc) and I cannot figure out where any of it is kept.

I'm assuming it's stored in the tile_blob column, but I can't find any information on accessing the data, just how to render the image. Right now I don't need to render the map, just to be able to query it.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Are you sure your mbtiles file contains vector data?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I'm not entirely sure, I was told that it should but I have no way of checking. How would I see if it does contain vector data? This is the first time I've ever looked at mapping etc, everything is new to me.

Comment: Related: [Read places information from a vector tile mbtiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/433341/201462).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mbtiles](https://www.mapbox.com/help/an-open-platform/#mbtiles) is a picture of the roads. Its a collection of PNG (or sometimes JPEG) images. That is what get stored in the [tiles table](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.1/spec.md#tiles), at different scales (known as zoom levels).

There is a vector addition known as [UTFGrid](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.1/utfgrid.md), which is more intended to do point to name lookup than to do linear / area features. That is, it isn't likely to contain the road geometry, but it might tell you which town or road you are hovering over.

Comment: I thought the same but apparently mbtiles can also store vector data (now?): "Vector tiles can also be stored in the MBTiles format; they’re not just for rasters!" from your link.

Comment: The vector part is UTFGrid. You could store arbitrary data including vectors in a sqlite table (as shown by geopackage and spatialite, amongst others), but that isn't per the mbtiles spec.

Comment: @BradHards The vector part is also Mapbox vector tiles https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/ and https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/. It is only loosely documented somewhere that vector tiles can be stored into MBTiles database.

Answer (score 2):

MBTiles can hold either raster tiles or vector tiles.
Vector tiles sample is available at https://github.com/klokantech/vector-tiles-sample and raster MBTiles you can create with GDAL v. 2.1 or later http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html

MBTiles db has a table "metadata" which can be used for checking if db contains rasters or vectors. The SQL query to use is

```
SELECT ROWID, "name", "value"
FROM "metadata"
WHERE "name"='format'
```

If format is "pbf" then the database is containing vectors, if "png" then rasters.

Comment: While you can put anything into a sqlite blob, I don't see anything in the mbtiles spec (1.0, 1.1 or 1.2) that permits or describes vector tiles (or geopackage binary, or spatialite, whatever). That is, I believe it is non-standard to do so.

Comment: It  is at least close to standard because MapBox is doing it with their MapBox Studio. They have just not updated the text of their MBTiles standard.