# Read places information from a vector tile mbtiles

Tags: vector-tiles, mbtiles

The data is not simply readable when I open the mbtiles in SQLite db browser. i.e. It's like this:
[image]

Let's say I want to search for a street name in the mbtiles. GeoServer is already doing this for me when I request a filter through WFS, so I suppose it's possible. I would like to know how to do this using SQL.

Comment: This isn't super helpful, but MBTile data is stored in a special format that needs to be decoded: https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.3/spec.md may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write this C# code that does this:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using System.IO.Compression;
using VectorTile;

Tile tile;
using var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=mymbtiles.mbtiles");
using (var command = new SqliteCommand("SELECT tile_data FROM images WHERE tile_id = '14/10201/9399'", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    var stream = reader.GetStream(0);
    using (var decompresser = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        tile = Tile.Parser.ParseFrom(decompresser);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(tile);
```

Before you run you need to compile [the Mapbox Vector Tile proto file](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/blob/master/2.1/vector_tile.proto) to get the `Tile` class. There's a guide on how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial), the output directory I used is the same as the `Program.cs` file. I Installed `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` and `Google.Protobuf` NuGet packages.

Also, as you can see the code is pretty simple you might be able to write it in another language yourself (in case you couldn't get C# to work).